# If statement returns false when it should be true

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

I have a javascript function to get a property from a style attribute.

I am then checking if the attribute is equal to a specific point.

However, when I `console.log()` the value of the attribute, it is as expected but when I test the attribute value, it returns as false?

here is my code and screenshots:

```
var $paywhirlWidget = $(".payment-signup-section .container .row .col-xs-12:first-child iframe#paywhirl_frame"),
        $widgetRow = $(".payment-signup-section .container .row .col-xs-12:first-child");

$.fn.inlineStyle = function (prop) {
    var styles = this.attr("style"),
        value;

    styles && styles.split(";").forEach(function (e) {
        var style = e.split(":");
        if ($.trim(style[0]) === prop) {
            value = style[1];
        }
    });
    return value;
};


function checkForChanges() {
    if ($(window).width() < 998) {
        console.log(Boolean($paywhirlWidget.inlineStyle("height").toLowerCase() == "620px"));
        console.log($paywhirlWidget.inlineStyle("height").toLowerCase());
        if ($paywhirlWidget.inlineStyle("height").toLowerCase() == "620px") {
            console.log("im here!!");
            $widgetRow.css("display", "none");
        }
    } else {
        if ($paywhirlWidget.inlineStyle("height") == "300px") {
            console.warn("im here too!!");
            $widgetRow.css("display", "none");
        }
    }
}

setInterval(checkForChanges, 500);
```

As an example, here is the "620px" test, as you can see, the first `console.log()` returns false, even though the second one shows the value as being exactly what I am testing for!

[image: error]

This is really confusing as I cannot understand why a value that is clearly true is returned as false when `Boolean` tested.

Comment: Quick note: There's no reason to ever use `Boolean`. The result of the comparison is already a boolean type.

Comment: Yeah, but using `Boolean` in the console.log tells me true or false, it was just type checking to be sure it was the if statement failing and not my code being a nuisance.

Comment: Still don't need to. The console will report it correctly regardless. It's impossible to say without reproducing it myself but is it possible that there's whitespace on the end of returned value? Try [`value = style[1].trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your style attribute has a space at the start of the value. Try using [trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

```
$.trim( $paywhirlWidget.inlineStyle("height").toLowerCase() ) === "620px"
```

Or update your inlineStyle plugin so that it does the trimming:

```
value = $.trim( style[1] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler to just use jQuery `height()` which returns number representing pixels

```
if ($paywhirlWidget.height() == 620)
```